# why a pointer to List can also point to Node?

Tags: c

I am a primer to c programming and reading c primer: 5th edition. What confuse me is why  `plist`  as a pointer to  List can also point to Node?

sorry, I did not paste function ListItemCount to the code block. In this function, `Node * pnode = *plist;`,  Does that mean `plist` was converted as a ponter point to `Node` ?  If so, why does the program need to convert to a pointer to node instead of assigning  `plist->head` to `pnode`(a pointer to Node)?

```
typedef struct film {
    char title[TSIZE];
    int rating;
} Item;

typedef struct node{
    Item item;
    // typical usage
    struct node * next;
} Node;


/*
* Note: to manage a linked list, we need  a pointer to its beginning,
* and we've used typedef to make List the name for a pointer of this
* type.
*/
typedef struct list{
    // should point to linked list Node
    Node * head;

    int size;
} List;

// TODO why  `plist`  as a pointer to  List can also point to Node?
/* returns number of nodes */
unsigned int ListItemCount(const List * plist)
{
    unsigned int count = 0;
    Node * pnode = *plist; /* set to start of list */
    while (pnode != NULL)
    {
        ++count;
        pnode = pnode->next; /* set to next node */
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: A pointer can point to anything. Things go wrong when you're trying to read from "meaningful" data from the said pointer. If you try to cast a `List` pointer to a `Node` pointer, you'll definitely get some compiler warnings.

Comment: It can't, not really. Why do you think that? Can you please elaborate on what confuses you?

Comment: In your code snippet `plist` is not used at all.

Comment: Nowhere in the code you posted `plist` is made to point to anything at all. What in this code made you believe that `plist` can also point to `Node`???

Comment: sorry, I forget part of the code block, the pointer conversion is in function `ListItemCount`

Comment: Have you tried compiling this code? I bet it didn't compile like this.

Comment: The compiler throw: `error: incompatible types when initializing type ‘Node *`, sorry,　I should compile by myself instead of just reading books!

Comment: @innerpeace well there you are then. It can't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you know that this doesn't work.

How should it work?

```
Node * pnode = *plist;
```

This was intended to get the first node. It actually tries to assign the list type as the first node. To make it work, we need to get the head node out of that.

```
Node * pnode = (*plist).head;
```

This now actually returns a `Node*`
To write this more succinctly:

```
Node * pnode = plist->head;
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler should shout warnings at you for that code.

However lets take a look at how it works...

The memory layout of the `List` structure is something like

```
+------+------+
| head | size |
+------+------+
```

<sub>(The above illustration ignores possible padding.)</sub>

The variable `plist` points to the beginning of that structure:

```
+------+------+
| head | size |
+------+------+
^
|
plist
```

As you can see it points to the location where `head` is stored. So by dereferencing `plist` we can get the `head` member.

But it is ***bad code*** and you should never write code like that. It makes code hard to read, understand and maintain. Be explicit and use

```
Node * pnode = plist->head; /* set to start of list */
```

instead.